# Using find vs. locate vs. whereis

Tags: touch, mv

I am doing Chapter 1 exercises from Linux Basics for Hackers (Starch Press):

> Create a new directory called hackerdirectory and create a new file in
>   that directory named hackedfile. Now copy that file to your /root
>   directory and then rename it secretfile.

So I did `mkdir hackerdirectory` then cd `hackerdirectory` then `touch hackedfile` then `sudo mv hackedfile /root`

My understanding is that `/root` is the top home directory but when I `cd ..` back to home and `ls -l`, it's not there:

```
drwxrwxr-x 23 nobu nobu    4096 Jul  9 18:24  anaconda3
-rw-r--r--  1 nobu nobu    4243 May  3 02:10  backblue.gif
-rw-rw-r--  1 nobu nobu   25120 Mar 23 07:02  CERTIFICATE
drwxrwxr-x  3 nobu nobu    4096 Mar 30 05:01  client-configs
-rw-rw-r--  1 nobu nobu     412 May  3 03:18  cookies.txt
-rw-------  1 root root 8560640 Apr 11 09:59  core
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobu nobu    4096 Sep 11 20:34  ctf
drwxr-xr-x 18 nobu nobu    4096 Sep 13 12:33  Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  4 nobu nobu    4096 Sep  8 18:59  Diamondhead
drwxrwxr-x  6 nobu nobu    4096 Sep 15 16:42  Documents
drwxr-xr-x 27 nobu nobu   12288 Sep 17 14:28  Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 nobu nobu    8980 Mar 20 06:44  examples.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 nobu nobu     828 May  3 02:10  fade.gif
drwxrwxr-x  4 nobu nobu    4096 Jun 27 02:38  fullstack
drwxrwxr-x 11 nobu nobu    4096 Jul 12 16:21  gym
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobu nobu    4096 Sep 17 15:37  hackerdirectory
drwx------  2 nobu nobu    4096 May  3 03:18  hts-cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 nobu nobu    2101 May  3 03:18  hts-log.txt
drwxr-xr-x  6 nobu nobu    4096 Sep  4 23:27  locust_k8s
drwxr-xr-x 10 nobu nobu    4096 Aug 28 11:44  mecab-ipadic-neologd
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobu nobu    4096 Mar 20 06:52  Music
drwxr-xr-x 14 nobu nobu    4096 Aug 24 14:10  myapp
drwx------  3 nobu nobu    4096 Mar 30 03:28  openvpn-ca
drwxr-xr-x  4 nobu nobu    4096 Aug 19 19:47  Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobu nobu    4096 Mar 20 06:52  Public
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobu nobu    4096 Aug 15 12:34  repos
drwxr-xr-x  6 nobu nobu    4096 Sep  4 23:23  snap
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobu nobu    4096 Mar 20 06:52  Templates
-rw-rw-r--  1 nobu nobu 5477405 Jul  5 08:17  tf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 nobu nobu 4474932 Oct 24  2017  unetbootin-linux-latest
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobu nobu    4096 Apr 27 11:56  Videos
drwx------  3 nobu nobu    4096 Jun 27 02:46 'VirtualBox VMs'
drwxrwxr-x  5 nobu nobu    4096 May  3 02:36  websites
drwxrwxr-x  2 nobu nobu    4096 Jul  9 21:15  work
```

Now I did:

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ locate hackedfile
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ whereis hackedfile
hackedfile:
```

What does this mean?  I've tried `sudo su` then `ls` but still can't see it.

Edit:  So I found it per the commands below but can't get rid of it.

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ sudo find /root -type f -name hackedfile
/root/hackedfile
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ sudo rm /root/hackedfile
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ sudo find /root -type f -name hackedfile
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ whereis hackedfile
hackedfile:
```

Edit (not listed)

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ sudo ls -al /root 
total 64
drwx------ 12 root root 4096 Sep 17 16:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 4096 Sep  9 12:45 ..
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jul 10 07:31 .aptitude
-rw-------  1 root root 1124 Sep 17 16:30 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Oct 23  2015 .bashrc
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Apr 11 05:47 .cache
drwx------  7 root root 4096 Apr 11 15:54 .config
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar 22 02:47 .dbus
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Apr 11 12:23 .gnupg
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Aug 17 09:20 .java
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr  1 08:12 .local
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 30 02:55 .nano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 21 11:13 .oracle_jre_usage
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148 Aug 18  2015 .profile
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Sep  4 22:58 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  220 Aug  8 14:02 .wget-hsts
```

Edit (when `sudo su`)

```
root@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:/home/nobu# whereis hackedfile
hackedfile:
```

So when I do command `whereis`, it shows the file.  So is it really deleted?

But now when I try: `sudo find /root -type f -name hackedfile` I get:

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$ sudo find /root -type f -name hackedfile
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~$
```

And thus it seems to be gone except doing `whereis' still shows it with the colon.

Edit:

Beware that `whereis` returns whatever you were looking for say `filename:` and then lists the PATH of location after colon.

So here is how to use `find`:

> find

That's from my textbook listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pwd` to see where you are in the file system. You will probably find the file using `sudo ls -al /root`

Comment: It didn't work, please see where I added the output in the question above.  `sudo find /root -type f -name hackedfile` found it but I cannot `cd /root` (permission denied) nor `sudo cd /root' (no command cd).

Comment: Your first edit says that you can't get rid of it but it appears you have - what is the goal here? Also you won't be able to run shell built in commands like `cd` - you will have to switch to the root user first: `su - root` and then run cd

Comment: Hey sorry about that.  I added the formatting but getting authentication failure for `su - root`.  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and `sudo su` works. Firstly I want to know why `hackedfile:` now has a colon after my original command to move the file and second, how to get rid of it.  I'll add some more edits in the question.

Comment: The "hackedfile:" is just whereis saying "You searched for 'hackedfile', here are the results...0 results". It looks to me like you successfully deleted the file with `sudo rm /root/hackedfile`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I had no idea when I do `whereis`, it lists whatever it is I am looking for then a colon and then the PATH.